# mongoid query, select more field return in json

Tags: ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I wan to get 2 url image from 2 devices. My model structure:

Compare: has_one :device1, has_one :device2

Device: has_one :image

Image: mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

In query I want to get JSON array compares from query

```
@compares = Compare.any_of({:device1_id.in => arr_device_id},{:device2_id.in => arr_device_id})
```

I try: (title is attr_accessor)

```
Compare.any_of({:device1_id.in => arr_device_id},{:device2_id.in => arr_device_id}).only(:title => 'abc'). Result json is not contain field title


@compare.to_json(:include => [:device1,:device2]) => this include device1 and device2 but not include image of it.


@compare.to_json(:method => [:title => 'abc'])   . Result json is not contain field title
```

Any solutions ? Thank for your help :D

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean `only(:title => "abc")` is to select only field "title" ?

Then, the solution may be replacing it with only(:title)

If what you mean only is where title is "abc" then replace `only(:title => "abc")` by `where(:title => "abc")`

to_json should work then.

Comment: No. I mean I want get more column that not contain in db.

It work now. Just add attr_writer :title. then call __.to_json(:methods => :title). Thank u for your answer :)